# Evaluating $\int_{S} (3z)^i dz$ from $1$ to $i+1$ where the principle branch of $(3z)^i$ is used.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this problem but here I face a nonsolvable integral.
The function to be integrated is $(3z)^i$. According to the Euler's formula $e^{(ix)} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, we can rewrite the function as $e^(i ln(3z))$. But remember that $ln(z) = ln\vert z\vert + i \arg(z)$ where $\vert z\vert$ is the magnitude of $z$ and $\arg(z)$ is the argument or phase of $z$. We are considering the principal branch of the logarithm, where $-\pi < \arg(z) <= \pi$.

In this case, I am trying to evaluate the integral of $(3z)^i$ along the line segment $S$ from $1$ to $1+i$.

So, if $z(t)$ is our parameterized curve where $z(t) = 1 + t*i,$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$, the derivative $dz/dt$ is simply $i$.

Then our function $(3z)^i$ will be transformed to $(3(1 + it))^i = exp(i * log(3(1 + it)))$. Now, the logarithm of a complex number $z = x + iy$, under the principal branch, is $log(z) = log|z| + i  Arg(z)$, where $|z|$ is the magnitude of $z$ and $Arg(z)$ is the argument of $z$.

Therefore, substituting this into the integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{(i ln(3(1+ti)))} i dt = i\int_{0}^{1} e^{(i(ln|3(1+ ti)| + i\arg(3(1+ ti))))} dt
\end{equation}

As we move from $1$ to $1+i$ along the line segment $S$, the magnitude $|3(1+ti)|$ changes from $3$ to $3\sqrt(2)$, and the argument $\arg(3(1+ti))$ changes from $0$ to $\pi/4$ (since $\arg(i) = \pi/2$ and we have $ti$).

So,

\begin{equation}
= \int_{0}^{1} e^{(i(ln(3) + ln(\sqrt{(1+t^2)}) + \pi t/2))} dt  = \int_{0}^{1} e^{(i(ln(3) + 1/2ln(1+t^2)))}e^{(i\pi t/2)} dt = i\int_{0}^{1} (3\sqrt{(1+t^2)})^i(\cos(\pi t/2) + i\sin(\pi t/2)) dt
\end{equation}

Now, this integral does not have a standard antiderivative that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Is there any problem with the above process?

Comment: The integrand is not the same as your last one, it is $e^{-{\rm arg}(3(1+it))}(\cos(\ln|3(1+it)|)+i\sin(\ln|3(1+it)|))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the expression $(3z)^i = e^{i\log(3z)}$ is not due to Euler's formula, rather by the definition of complex exponentiation.

If you use a specific branch, then ordinary differentiation rules work. That is, $\frac{d}{dz}(3z)^{1+i} = (1+i)(3z)^i\cdot 3$. This is justified by chain rule and the definition $e^{i\log(3z)}$. Hence the integral is just the difference of  antiderivative $\frac{1}{3(1+i)}(3z)^{1+i}$, which is easily evaluated.